# Styling issue with ticker

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the javascript ticker code found [here](http://www.haragei.com/blog/jquery-horizontal-ticker/).

In Chrome and Safari, the ticker displays where it should:

[image]

In Firefox, it displays below the 2012 Entrants section:

[image]

Complete code [here](http://www.esthermstrom.com/ticker/index.php). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#ticker-parent{
width:800px;
float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the following CSS, that should fix in all the browsers:

```
#ticker-parent {
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    width: 960px;
}
```

Basically just put the marquee inline...